# Открыть доступ к методу api

Tags: php, yii2

Возможно-ли в yii2 при использовании аутентификатора, открыть доступ к какому-либо методу(-ам)(в моем случае actionParents) для неаутентифицированного пользователя

```
namespace app\modules\api\controllers;


use app\models\Department;
use app\models\User;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\filters\auth\HttpBasicAuth;
use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class DepartmentController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\Department';

    public function behaviors()
    {
        return array_merge(parent::behaviors(), [
            'basicAuth' => [
                'class' => HttpBasicAuth::class,
                'auth' => function ($u, $p) {
                    $user = User::findOne(['username' => $u]);
                    return $user->validatePassword($p) ? $user : null;
                }
            ],
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::class,
                'only' => ['parents'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'allow' => true,
                        'actions' => ['parents'],
                        'roles' => ['?'], // тут как бы должно произойти чудо, но нет
                    ],
                ]
            ],
        ]);
    }

    public function actionParents($id)
    {
        return new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => Department::find()->parents($id)
        ]);
    }
}
```

Сейчас неаутентифицированный пользователь видит:

```
{
    "name": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Your request was made with invalid credentials.",
    "code": 0,
    "status": 401,
    "type": "yii\\web\\UnauthorizedHttpException"
}
```

Comment: В basicAuth можно добавить исключение на экшн парентс? Похоже он блочит все и до акцессконтрол дело не доходит.

Comment: @fedornabilkin Все верно, до AccessControl дело не доходит. Как выглядит исключение на parents в basicAuth?

Comment: Надо смотреть в классе. Возможно что-то такое `'except' => ['parents']`, а может там вообще такого нету :)